OSError: Bad file descriptor
I'm trying to run celery beat worker and a normal celery worker as docker containers. I have my tasks in flask application.
The normal celery worker is working fine but getting following error in beat worker
[2024-08-07 09:57:24,692: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2024-08-07 09:57:25,413: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2024-08-07 09:57:25,416: ERROR/Beat] Process Beat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/billiard-4.2.0-py3.11.egg/billiard/process.py", line 323, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery-5.4.0-py3.11.egg/celery/beat.py", line 718, in run
    self.service.start(embedded_process=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery-5.4.0-py3.11.egg/celery/beat.py", line 634, in start
    humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 40, in __get__
    return super().__get__(instance, owner)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/functools.py", line 1001, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery-5.4.0-py3.11.egg/celery/beat.py", line 677, in scheduler
    return self.get_scheduler()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery-5.4.0-py3.11.egg/celery/beat.py", line 667, in get_scheduler
    aliases = dict(load_extension_class_names(extension_namespace))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery-5.4.0-py3.11.egg/celery/utils/imports.py", line 150, in load_extension_class_names
    _entry_points = entry_points(group=namespace)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1041, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 476, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1038, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                                       ^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 955, in _normalized_name
    or super()._normalized_name
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 627, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
                              ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 622, in name
    return self.metadata['Name']
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 611, in metadata
    or self.read_text('PKG-INFO')
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 939, in read_text
    return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 2468, in read_text
    with self.open('r', encoding, *args, **kwargs) as strm:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 2434, in open
    stream = self.root.open(self.at, zip_mode, pwd=pwd)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1579, in open
    fheader = zef_file.read(sizeFileHeader)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 786, in read
    self._pos = self._file.tell()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

I'm using python 3.11.9-slim as the base image for the celery beat worker
Following is the versions of the packages installed in the container
amqp==5.2.0
attrs==24.1.0
billiard==4.2.0
blinker==1.8.2
boto3==1.34.145
botocore==1.34.145
celery==5.4.0
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.17.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
CIRAUtils==9.0.0
click==8.1.7
click-didyoumean==0.3.1
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.3.0
cobble==0.1.4
cryptography==43.0.0
cssselect==1.2.0
dnspython==2.6.1
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
flasgger==0.9.7.1
Flask==3.0.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.1
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.6.0
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
gunicorn==22.0.0
idna==3.7
importlib_metadata==8.2.0
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
jmespath==1.0.1
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
kombu==5.3.7
lxml==5.2.2
mammoth==1.8.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
mistune==3.0.2
msal==1.30.0
numpy==2.0.1
openpyxl==3.1.5
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.2.2
prompt_toolkit==3.0.47
pycparser==2.22
pycryptodome==3.20.0
PyJWT==2.8.0
pymongo==4.8.0
pyquery==2.0.0
python-dateutil==2.9.0
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
redis==5.0.7
referencing==0.35.1
requests==2.32.3
rpds-py==0.19.1
s3transfer==0.10.2
sentry-sdk==2.10.0
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.2
vine==5.1.0
wcwidth==0.2.13
Werkzeug==3.0.3
xmltodict==0.12.0
zipp==3.19.2

CIRAUtils==9.0.0 is custom package

The issue was with the installation of my custom python package CIRAUtils. I was using the command
python setup.py install.
Starting with Python 3.11, the preferred way to install packages is using tools like pip or build rather than python setup.py install.
So I installed my custom python package by generating wheel file and installed the .whl using the command pip install cutom-package.whl. Doing this resolved my issue.
